# no type named ‘completion_handler_type’ in ‘class boost::asio::async_result’

Tags: boost

I am trying to write a stackful coroutine that can be called using boost::spawn. The coroutine starts a thread internally, waits for the thread to finish, and obtains an integer value generated by the thread as the return value of the coroutine. However, I encountered an error. Can any experts please help me take a look? My environment is: Ubuntu22.04, GCC9.2 ,Boost1.81.

```
// TestAsync.cpp : 此文件包含 "main" 函数。程序执行将在此处开始并结束。
//
 
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>
 
 
template<typename CompletionToken>
BOOST_ASIO_INITFN_RESULT_TYPE(CompletionToken, void(boost::system::error_code, int))
async_do_something(BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_ARG(CompletionToken) token)
{
    boost::asio::async_completion<CompletionToken, void(boost::system::error_code, int)> completion(token);
 
    boost::async(boost::launch::async, [handler = completion.completion_handler]() mutable
    {
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        int result = 0;
 
        // 执行操作，并拿到result或ec...
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        result = 100;
 
        auto executor = boost::asio::get_associated_executor(handler);
        boost::asio::dispatch(executor, [ec, handler, result]() mutable
        {
            handler(ec, result);
        });
    });
 
    return completion.result.get();
}
 
void MyCoroutine(boost::asio::yield_context yield) {
    std::cout << "进入MyCoroutine" << std::endl;
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    int n = async_do_something(yield[ec]);
    if (ec)
        std::cerr << ec.message() << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
    std::cout << "离开MyCoroutine" << std::endl;
}
 
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
 
    boost::asio::spawn(ioc, MyCoroutine);
    ioc.run();
}
```

$ g++ -c -I../boost_1_81_0 main.cpp

```
In file included from ../boost_1_81_0/boost/asio/detail/handler_type_requirements.hpp:53,
                 from ../boost_1_81_0/boost/asio/impl/execution_context.hpp:18,
                 from ../boost_1_81_0/boost/asio/execution_context.hpp:409,
                 from ../boost_1_81_0/boost/asio/any_io_executor.hpp:23,
                 from ../boost_1_81_0/boost/asio/spawn.hpp:19,
                 from main.cpp:5:
../boost_1_81_0/boost/asio/async_result.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::asio::async_completion<boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::any_io_executor>, void(boost::system::error_code, int)>’:
main.cpp:14:87:   required from ‘typename boost::asio::async_result<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type, void(boost::system::error_code, int)>::return_type async_do_something(CompletionToken&&) [with CompletionToken = boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::any_io_executor>; typename boost::asio::async_result<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type, void(boost::system::error_code, int)>::return_type = int]’
main.cpp:38:38:   required from here
../boost_1_81_0/boost/asio/async_result.hpp:651:9: error: no type named ‘completion_handler_type’ in ‘class boost::asio::async_result<boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::any_io_executor>, void(boost::system::error_code, int)>’
  651 |         completion_handler_type;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../boost_1_81_0/boost/asio/async_result.hpp:684:62: error: no type named ‘completion_handler_type’ in ‘class boost::asio::async_result<boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::any_io_executor>, void(boost::system::error_code, int)> ’
  684 |     completion_handler_type&, completion_handler_type>::type completion_handler;
      |                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘typename boost::asio::async_result<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type, void(boost::system::error_code, int)>::return_type async_do_something(CompletionToken&&) [with CompletionToken = boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::any_io_executor>; typename boost::asio::async_result<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type, void(boost::system::error_code, int)>::return_type = int]’:
main.cpp:38:38:   required from here
main.cpp:16:59: error: ‘struct boost::asio::async_completion<boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::any_io_executor>, void(boost::system::error_code, int)>’ has no member named ‘completion_handler’; did you mean ‘completion_handler_type’?
   16 |  boost::async(boost::launch::async, [handler = completion.completion_handler]() mutable
      |                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                completion_handler_type
main.cpp:32:27: error: ‘class boost::asio::async_result<boost::asio::basic_yield_context<boost::asio::any_io_executor>, void(boost::system::error_code, int)>’ has no member named ‘get’
   32 |  return completion.result.get();
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues/1255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a regression [since boost 1.80.0](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/8oTKvG49G) (follow link to side-by-side comparison 1.79.0 vs 1.80.0).

It works with 1.79.0, although you needed a workguard to make it complete:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cba47eb39e132f93)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

template <typename CompletionToken>
BOOST_ASIO_INITFN_RESULT_TYPE(CompletionToken, void(boost::system::error_code, int))
async_do_something(CompletionToken&& token) {
    asio::async_completion<CompletionToken, void(boost::system::error_code, int)> completion(token);

    boost::async(boost::launch::async,
                 [handler = completion.completion_handler,
                  work    = make_work_guard(completion.completion_handler)]() mutable {
                     boost::system::error_code ec;
                     int                       result = 0;

                     std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
                     result = 100;

                     auto executor = asio::get_associated_executor(handler);
                     asio::dispatch(executor,
                                    [ec, handler, result]() mutable { handler(ec, result); });
                 });

    return completion.result.get();
}

void MyCoroutine(asio::yield_context yield) {
    std::cout << "Enter MyCoroutine" << std::endl;
    boost::system::error_code ec;

    if (int n = async_do_something(yield[ec]); ec)
        std::cerr << ec.message() << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << n << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Leave MyCoroutine" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    asio::spawn(ioc, MyCoroutine);
    ioc.run();
}
```

Printing

```
Enter MyCoroutine
100
Leave MyCoroutine
```

To work around it for 1.80.0/1.81.0 I suggest doing the `async_result` steps manually, or using `async_initiate` as documented here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/completion_tokens.html

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb7a22224caa899c)**

```
template <typename Token>
typename asio::async_result<typename std::decay<Token>::type,
                            void(boost ::system ::error_code, int)>::return_type
async_do_something(Token&& token) {
    auto init = [](auto handler) {
        boost::async( //
            boost::launch::async,
            [handler = std::move(handler), work = make_work_guard(handler)]() mutable {
                boost::system::error_code ec;
                int result = 0;

                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
                result = 100;

                auto executor = asio::get_associated_executor(handler);
                asio::dispatch(executor, [ec, handler = std::move(handler), result]() mutable {
                    std::move(handler)(ec, result);
                });
            });
    };

    return asio::async_initiate<Token, void(boost::system::error_code, int)>(init, token);
}
```

Printing the same. Also works with 1.80.0 and 1.81.0: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/brrYrW1sY

My intuition tells me this change has to do with move-only-handler support, but I don't really see a culprit right away.

Comment: Tested and effective, your skills are superb, thank you.